# How to create .NET 6 WinForms Toolbar Icons that look like standard ones

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a toolbar for .NET 6 (WinForms) application.  The Visual Studio Image library provides some great icons.  However, the PNGs are only 16x16. For some reason my toolstrip defaults to a height of 31pix and the toolstripbutton icons become stretched and blurry. This is not acceptable.  (Note there is one combobox on the toolstrip.)

I'd love to be able to convert the SVGs in the Visual Studio Image Library, but they also come out blurry when changed to anything other than 16x16.

What is a recommended approach and resolution for creating sharp toolbar button icons that fit the look of the standard icons obtained from the "Insert Standard Items" tool?

Comment: https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png

Comment: [Material Design Icons](https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/) use `Advanced PNG Export...` or add an `MdiParent Form` with a toolbar that includes several standard buttons with icons. You can also find several icons in the BindingNavigator component, which is available in .NET Framework 4+.

Answer (score 1):

> but they also come out blurry when changed to anything other than 16x16.

I think you should choose another converter, I tried to use GIMP to convert some SVGs to 31px PNGs, they look good.

[image: ActivityMonitor] [image: SystemInfo] [image: GetDynamicValuePropertyGroup]